# Problems Closing or reloading a "popup" window

Tags: javascript, popup, refresh, reload

I am having trouble finding a way to close or reload a popup box generated by the code below. What is happening that I want to avoid is that if the user does not Close the window manually and then selects another "TIP", the new tip is simply appended to the existing text. A desired result would be either;

1. The window closes when focus is lost from the window, thus resetting it.
2. I can "refresh" the window when pasting a new tip.

I have done extensive research and tried so many different approaches to no avail.

Keep in mind, I am working withing a tight government environment and they are very testy about installing third party tools such as jQuery or similar, so I am really stuck with working with the basics here until I can convince them otherwise. Also, for the MOST part, most users in the department will be using IE8 or higher, but (as a lower priority) I would rather develop a solution that isn't restrictive to a specific browser.

Maybe someone can suggest a better way of doing what I am doing, or is that asking too much? ;-) Thanks in advance.

```
function PromptTip(title, message)
{
var HTMLTitle = "<p style='text-align:center'><b>" + title + "</b></p>"
var HTMLMsg = "<p style='text-align:center'>" + message + "</p>"
win = window.open("","Tip","width=320,height=210,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,titlebar=no");
win.moveTo(screen.width/2-160,screen.height/2-105)
win.document.writeln("<html><head><title>Prompt Tip</title></head><body onfocusout='javascript:close()'>");
win.document.writeln(HTMLTitle);
win.document.writeln(HTMLMsg);
win.document.writeln("<p style='text-align:center'><a href='javascript:close()'>close</a></p></body></html>");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly recommend against using window.open and window.document.writeln. In place of window.open I would recommend dynamically creating markup (or showing a hidden snippet of markup) and use absolute positioning as all modern dialog/modal JS libraries do. In place of win.document.writeln I would recommend using DOM creationing using [document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createElement) and insertion using [Node.appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild) (or any number of DOM insertion methods) OR using a markup template approach.

That said, you could simply modify your code to replace the entire innerHTML of the body of the iframe every time a tooltip is clicked.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ruJqj/

```
function PromptTip(title, message) {
    var HTMLTitle = "<p style='text-align:center'><b>" + title + "</b></p>"
    var HTMLMsg = "<p style='text-align:center'>" + message + "</p>"
    win = window.open("", "Tip", "width=320,height=210,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,titlebar=no");
    win.moveTo(screen.width / 2 - 160, screen.height / 2 - 105)

    win.document.body.innerHTML = HTMLTitle + HTMLMsg + "<p style='text-align:center'><a href='javascript:close()'>close</a></p>";
}​
```

Comment: Thanks for the Tip Adam. I shall look into those options you suggest, and while your suggested coding certainly stream-lines my code, I still have the bigger problem about closing or refreshing... Will the coding alternatives you suggest (document.element, etc) make that any easier do you think?

Comment: This works very well. Just the suggested change to innerHTML did the trick. Thanks again.

Comment: Only one thins I need to add to this after that change - a Return to Top/Focus line... Heh he.

Comment: And Success. Thanks again Adam. I have decided to go with the Code you suggested as the result needs to be a popup and from what I can see of the element code, that is in-line. Correct me if I am wrong there.

Comment: The dialog/modals that are all done with with dynamic markup appear as a popup and can be made to simulate a modal window. A search on google/github for "simple javascript dialog" might do the trick. Check out this page for the basics: http://raventools.com/blog/create-a-modal-dialog-using-css-and-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

If I understud your question may this can help, you change this line:

```
    win.document.writeln("<html><head><title>Prompt Tip</title></head><body onfocusout='javascript:close()'>");
```

For this one:

```
    win.document.writeln("<html><head><title>Prompt Tip</title></head><body onBlur='javascript:close()'>");
```

You need to use this event: onBlur='javascript:close()'

*I just test it in IE 9 and it's working fine

Comment: Sorry Russo - Does not work for me. Window loads but when I click out, it stays open.

Comment: Did you chek the "popup protection" of your explorer? Becouse if you don't allow it to exploit your js code this will not work.

Comment: Ahh, well there we may have a problem. Remember I said that Our Tech area is a little tight? Well many of our IE settings are locked down. However, I have no problem Loading the Popup. That works fine...

Comment: Oh right, whell anyway Adam already helped you, good luck for the next, and try to convice them to use at least jquery, this library just simplify the life xD.

Comment: Thanks for the help all the same.